# C# Load from Xml to Listview

Tags: c#, xml, listview

How can I load this Xml file at startup?
I can save it but I dont know how to load it

I want that it will load at the program start.

This is my Code for saving:

```
private void button_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fileStream;
    StreamWriter streamWriter;
    XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter;
    string filename = @"c:\Users\Christoph\Documents\Overview.txt";

    try
    {
        // overwrite even if it already exists
        fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(streamWriter);
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Items");

        const int SUBITEM1_POS = 0;
        const int SUBITEM2_POS = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            String currentSubItem1 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[SUBITEM1_POS].Text;
            String currentSubItem2 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[SUBITEM2_POS].Text;

            xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Item");
            xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("subitem1", currentSubItem1.ToString());
            xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("subitem2", currentSubItem2.ToString());
            xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }

        xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();
        xmlTextWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // do something about your error

    }
}
```

And this is what it writes into the Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
  <Item subitem1="Test1" subitem2="1" />
  <Item subitem1="Test2" subitem2="2" />
  <Item subitem1="Test3" subitem2="3" />
  <Item subitem1="Test4" subitem2="4" />
</Items>
```

Comment: First load the file, then you can use [LINQ-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).  Without any other specifics in your question, this is really the only advice we can offer.

Comment: Well, we can also suggest that your writing code would be simpler using LINQ to XML as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In .Net there are several possible methods for loading xml.

Theese includes:

- XmlDocument
- XDocument
- XmlReader/XmlTextReader
- XmlSerializer/DataContractSerializer

With XmlDocument and XDocument the xml is loaded into an object structure. XDocument uses Linq for navigation. XmlReader reads the xml sequentially and could be used if it is to big to be loaded into an object structure. With the serializer objects could be written to xml and read from it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument()
doc.Load(filename);
foreach (var item in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
{       
   listView.Items.Add(((XmlNode)item).InnerText)
}
```

Comment: And how can I load it IN the listView?

Comment: Thanks. But what is the "InnerText"? I get an error. Must I replace it like I replaced the filename?

Comment: Well that's how it SHOULD work... but now that I look at your XML, since you store your data in attributes instead, you need to use item.Attributes to get each attribute

Comment: Something like this: item.Attributes["subitem1"].Value

Comment: Hmm that also doesnt work. When I type "item." only 4 things are showing (Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString)
Thats the only Error I get now

Comment: I is all fine but that what it should do doesnt work. It will not show it in the listview I also tried to load it with a button not on formload but it also doesnt work.

I hope you doesnt hate me because I ask so many things ;)
You must only help me if you want. But really thanks. And also sorry for my kind of bad English^